How to get the error log link from notarytool?
I am in the process of notarizing a dmg file. We are getting some errors in the process. These errors can be retrieved from the notarytool -log option. However, I would like to get the error in a link form like we used to get with altool so that I could share it with my team. Does anyone know how to get a link for the failure log?
